# iOS-Charts draw slice text outside the slices in pie chart

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I want to draw the slice text outside the slices in pie chart, like in this image:

[slice text outside slices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KljGE.png)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
pieChartDataSet.xValuePosition = .OutsideSlice
```

Comment: this solution unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used pie charts myself yet in ios-charts, but just looking at this (unfortunately incomplete) documentation , I would suggest trying to alter some of the values in the `PieChartDataSet`.

In Particular, `xValuePosition`, `yValuePosition` or `ValuePosition`.

In the bar chart class it is done like so `barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom`, hence my thinking it may be one of the above values. So have a play around and hopefully that helps you out! :)

Documentation: [Charts Docs - PieChartDataSet](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Charts/2.2.5/Classes/PieChartDataSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this lines

```
charDataSet.valueFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
charDataSet.valueLinePart1OffsetPercentage = 0.8
charDataSet.valueLinePart1Length = 0.05
charDataSet.valueLinePart2Length = 0.05
charDataSet.valueLineWidth = 0
charDataSet.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice

chart.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0
chart.holeColor = nil
chart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.8
chart.legend.enabled = false
chart.animate(xAxisDuration: 1)
chart.drawSlicesUnderHoleEnabled = false
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with [iOS chart](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/) , feature which you are expecting is not yet available.

[Please refer](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/743).

Either you move with other library or still you could make max as per attached image.

[image]

[You can download this code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKOHgzekJ3bnNOcWc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can try the following. If using PieChart it will draw the value outside of the slice with some line pointing to the right slice.

```
dataSet.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice
```

Above will give you the following result

[image: PieChart Demo]